# How was Kung Fu Panda received in China?

Tags: kung-fu-panda, reception

Considering that the film is an American kung-fu production which takes on Chinese traditions and culture, how was it received in China? Did local critics consider it a humorous animated Chinese tale? Or was it derided for being an inaccurate portrayal, a parody, or a Western stereotyping of Chinese culture?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_Fu_Panda#Box_office)

> Kung Fu Panda was also well received in China. It made nearly 110
>   million Chinese Yuan by July 2, 2008, becoming the first animated film
>   to make more than 100 million Yuan in Chinese box offices. The
>   Chinese director Lu Chuan commented, "From a production standpoint,
>   the movie is nearly perfect. Its American creators showed a very
>   sincere attitude about Chinese culture." With the film's
>   success at the Chinese box office, some people within China have
>   questioned the quality of China's domestic animations. The fact that
>   such a successful film based on Chinese culture was created by the
>   American film industry has led to some Chinese introspection.

So it looks like it was well received in China.

Comment: Sounds like it hasn't been that well received by China's animation industry though. :)

Comment: Afterall who wouldn't love Po, uh.. I mean the Dragon Warrior ;)

Comment: They even made a movie similar in style to it, with a rabbit protagonist and a snow-leopard-disguised-as-a-panda antagonist, but with little success in replicating Kung Fu Panda's Success

Comment: @Fikko3107 What was it called?

Comment: At first I completely forgot the title. But after a little googling, I found it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_a_Rabbit

Comment: And they even making a sequel of it...... shhh....